# Como puedo redirigir a una URL externa en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

Estoy construyendo una aplicacion web con Angular y necesito redirigir hacia una URL externa, si alguien sabe como se haria me seria de mucha ayuda, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como en cualquier página web, puedes hacer algo como location.href= <URL>

Comment: Eso lo haria en el archivo typescript?

Comment: Sí, por ejemplo... aunque como no has puesto detalles de lo que quieres hacer no puedo confirmarte de que sea la opción perfecta.

Comment: Quiero agregar un enlace para que me redirija a una url externa, cuando lo hago con el href angular me redirige al componente de NotFound porque por defecto angular entiende que es una url interna de la aplicacion

Comment: la URL es completa?, ¿con https://... al inicio?

Comment: Agregue ahora la URL completa con el https y me funciona ya, gracias bro